# Implement Dense_rank function without using window function in hive

Tags: hive, dense-rank, windowing

I am trying to implement dense rank function without using using window function (dense_rank).

In tried with following query:

```
select deptID, salary, 
(select count(distinct Salary) 
 from Employee e 
 where e.deptID = Employee.deptID and e.salary >= Employee.Salary) as dense_rank 
from Employee order by deptID, Salary Desc;
```

I am getting following error while executing this query in hive:

> NoViableAltException(244@[435:1: precedenceEqualExpression : ( ( LPAREN precedenceBitwiseOrExpression COMMA )=> precedenceEqualExpressionMutiple | precedenceEqualExpressionSingle );])
>       at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
>       at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceEqualExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceNotExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10008)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAndExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10127)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10286)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.expression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6218)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.expression(HiveParser.java:51844)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectItem(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:2951)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectList(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:1467)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectClause(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:1194)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectClause(HiveParser.java:51847)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectStatement(HiveParser.java:45661)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:45568)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:44584)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:44454)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1696)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1178)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:404)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:329)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1158)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1253)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>   FAILED: ParseException line 1:24 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'count' in expression specification

Please let me how to overcome this error and we can get the same functionality as of Dense rank without using `dense_rank()`

Comment: what's the reason you want to avoid `dense_rank`?

Comment: I am not avoiding the use of it. Eager to know the other way to use this functionality.